# How can I setup a subdomain only in AWS Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have a domain that's hosted by a hosting provider. I'd like to configure a subdomain of it to use an AWS elastic IP address I have that's used by an EC2 instance. Here's what I've done so far, but it still doesn't work.

1. Created an A record for the subdomain on the hosting provider's server
2. Created a Route 53 public hosted zone
3. Added an A record for the subdomain to the Route 53 zone
4. All routing policies in the zone are set to "Simple"
5. Created 4 NS records on the domain registrar for the subdomain that point to the Name Servers the Route 53 zone uses

When I ping it I get "cannot resolve sub.domain.com: Unknown host"

Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need Route53 at all if you just want to point a single subdomain A record at your elastic IP. Just create the A record with the IP address in your current DNS provider.

Comment: I tried that at first and it didn't work. At your suggestion I tried it again after deleting the Route 53 zone and undoing all other changes. I have a single A record with the DNS provider that points the subdomain to the IP address. I still get "can't resolve ... unknown host" when I ping it. Is there a delay before the A record is recognized?

Comment: There can be a big delay depending on the TTL settings at the DNS provider. There are online tools such as this one to help debug this: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/

Comment: I thought I had set the TTL to 7200, but it's at 14400. I'll give it some more time. Thx for pointing me to that google apps tool!

Comment: If it isn't resolving at all, I wouldn't expect the DNS to cache it for very long. You might try some other tools like https://www.nslookup.io/

Comment: Just tried the nslookup tool. No A record is showing for all 5 DNS tabs for the subdomain (the domain by itself shows all of its records accurately in all tabs). I double checked the IP address I entered and the spelling of the subdomain.domain.com and they're both correct. Any other ideas?

Comment: It seems like there's something wrong with the way you created the record on your DNS provider. Do you have other records at that provider that are working?

Comment: The domain uses Cloudflare as a CDN for the website. I took a second look at the records using the tools you suggested and noticed they were all from Cloudflare, not my hosting provider. Once I created the A record on Cloudflare it worked. Thanks for your help, Mark. I also bookmarked your website to see what other useful tidbits of info I can pick up.